# insert ng-click event into ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, events, angular-ui, ng-grid, angularjs-ng-click

i want to do something that i don't know if it is possible

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Custom Plunker</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

## JS

```
// main.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
    $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData',
                         cellTemplate:'<div class="ngCellText" ><a ng-click="foo()">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</a></div>' 
    }
    $scope.foo = function() {  

        alert('');
    };
});
```

I want to put a ng-click event on a row in a ng-grid,i have take the idea looking around, but I don't really understand if it is possible and, if it is so, if that's the right way to do that.
In this code, that seems to be good to me, the app doesn't start the alert, any suggest or ideas?

Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/U6wdWTAV30HRhJk8xFPA?p=preview

Comment: thanks but it didn't work do you have any idea why?have you try the plunker?

Comment: This is a very late answer to this question, but I was working with the same problem. The example given in the answer by @mainguy didn't really address the problem with the click event on the input control.  Here is a working example. hth.  http://plnkr.co/edit/6IWa29ewYywLI1ghPgxe?p=preview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These definitions work for me:

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: [{
        field: 'name',
        displayName: 'Name',
        cellTemplate: '<div  ng-click="foo()" ng-bind="row.getProperty(col.field)"></div>'
      }, {
        field: 'age',
        displayName: 'Age',
        cellTemplate: '<div  ng-click="foo()" ng-bind="row.getProperty(col.field)"></div>'
      }

    ]
  };
```

See your forked Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/siauaez3iA4FUWVMQgLJ?p=preview)

Comment: The correct answer is to use `grid.appScope`, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33792526/492130

Comment: Yes, I know. But this question was about ng-grid not ui-grid. Thanks anyhow for pointing this out.

Comment: Right! Thanks for updating this. I forgot to mention that `ng-grid` has been deprecated in favor of `ui-grid`. So if you can move to `ui-grid`, you should move and you should use `grid.appScope`.

Comment: But what happens when you want to move but you can't move? Mr. Anderson? :-)

Comment: Quit your job, lawyer up, hit the gym!

Answer (score 10):

The document on their github site is really old.

here is a link to the right page for this problem.
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_appScope

```
        yourCtrl.gridOptions = {
            enableFiltering: true,
            enableHiding : false,
            enableSorting: true,
            appScopeProvider : yourCtrl,
            rowTemplate: '<div ng-click="grid.appScope.doSomething(row)" ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="col.colIndex()" ui-grid-cell></div>',
        };

        yourCtrl.doSomething = function(row) {
            alert("lala");
        }
```

yes,  somehow

```
ng-click="grid.appScope.doSomething"
```

won't work

Answer (score 6):

```
$scope.ShowDetails=function(_obj)
{
   alert('Hi! ' + _obj);
}

$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
      { name: 'Search', field: 'Col1', cellTemplate: '<div ng-click="grid.appScope.ShowDetails(row)"><img src="/images/search.png" /></div>' },
      { name: 'Col2', displayName: 'Col2' },
    ]};
```

Here the example to attach an event to a ui grid cell.