# is there any inbuilt right click event in ng-grid using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

i am using angularjs to write right click event for selected row in ng-grid.but i want to know is any inbuilt right click event there in ng-grid.if it is there please suggest me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A directive may be used to bind required actions on a right click, by using `contextmenu` event.

You can also refer to answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731634/how-do-i-handle-right-click-events-in-angular-js).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define a celltemplate with the required conditions. Something like this by defining a directive
[insert ng-click event into ng-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073714/insert-ng-click-event-into-ng-grid)