# Invoking a function inside controller from ng-click in ng-grid is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-grid

I got stuck while calling a function inside controller(listCtrl)  from `ng-click` inside `ng-grid`

**asset.js.coffee**

```
app = angular.module('asset',[]).namespace(true)
            app.controller 'linkCtrl', ['$scope','Restangular','asset.ProcServiceTools',($scope,Restangular,ProcServiceTools) ->  
              Restangular.all('asset').customGETLIST("linktogroup",{}).then (data) ->
                $scope.myData = data
                $scope.dynamicColumnDefs =ProcServiceTools.getIndexDynamicColumnDefs(data)
              $scope.customoptions = ProcServiceTools.getCustomOptions()
              $scope.linking = () ->
                console.log("checkout")
            ]
            app.service 'ProcServiceTools', () ->
              class Tools
                getIndexDynamicColumnDefs: (data) ->
                  return [
                    {field: 'id', displayName: 'ID' },
                    {field: 'asset_group_id', displayName: 'Group_ID' },
                    {field:'asset_catalog_id', displayName:'Catalog_id' },
                    {field: 'condition', displayName: 'Condition' },
                    {field: 'notes', displayName: 'Notes' },
                    {field: 'status', displayName: 'Status' },
                    {field: 'current_user_id', displayName: 'Current_user' },
                    {field: '' , cellTemplate: "<button  ng-click='linking()'>Link-to </button>"}]
                getCustomOptions: () ->
                  return {
                    showGroupPanel: true
                    jqueryUIDraggable: true
                    showSelectionCheckbox: true
                    showFooter: true
                    selectWithCheckboxOnly: true
                    enableColumnResize: true
                  }
              new Tools
```

This is my asset.js file...I have injected the ProcServiceTools inside my linkCtrl and called the getIndexDynamicColumnDefs function inside this service with data as paramter and it get assigned to $scope.myData and i have also added linking() to the $scope

And this is my

**index.html.erb**

```
<div ng-controller='asset.linkCtrl'>
<customgrid columndefs='dynamicColumnDefs' data='myData' dirclass='gridStyleTable' include-search='true' options='customoptions'></customgrid>
```

In this file i set the data to be myData.I am getting all the datas displayed and button is also getting displayed..My problem is ng-click in the getIndexDynamicCoulmnDefs  is not getting triggered when i click the link-to button...

But when i insert a button inside index.html.erb it is triggering the function.See the below code.The inserted button link is triggering the `linking()`.

```
                <div ng-controller='asset.linkCtrl'>
                <customgrid columndefs='dynamicColumnDefs' data='myData' dirclass='gridStyleTable' include-search='true' options='customoptions'></customgrid>
            <button ng-click="linking()">link</button>
            </div>
```

I dont know the reason why i cant call the function inside the controller from ng-clik in ng-grid.

Comment: Hey, can you post error from console.

Comment: You might be have the same problem I had, ng-grid reportedly introduces a new scope in the hierarchy, so you need to call into  $scope.$parent, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744561/ng-click-inside-cell-template-does-not-trigger-function-in-controller/28794399#28794399

Comment: @Fasermaler That sounds kinda hacky no? :S

Comment: @prasanthv not really, it's just how ui grid works. I managed to confuse myself now though, so thanks for the heads-up. I think it should be grid.appscope... silly scopes :)  check http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_appScope

Comment: @prasanthv,Fasermaler Thanks for ur solutions..I got it working..It didnt get triggered because of my mistake which i have posted in my solution !!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of my user defined customgrid directive which i have included in index.html.erb that has its own private scope..So i used ng-grid itself and got that function triggered...

```
app = angular.module('asset', []).namespace(true);
            app.controller('linkCtrl', ['$scope', 'Restangular', function($scope, Restangular) {
                $scope.linking = function() {
                   console.log("check me out");
                };
                 Restangular.all('asset').customGETLIST("linktogroup", {}).then(function(data) {
                  $scope.myData = data;
                });
                    $scope.gridOptions = { 
                                data: 'myData',
                           columnDefs: [{field: 'id', displayName: 'ID' },
                                                {field: 'asset_group_id', displayName: 'Group_ID' },
                                                {field:'asset_catalog_id', displayName:'Catalog_id' },
                                                {field: 'condition', displayName: 'Condition' },
                                                {field: 'notes', displayName: 'Notes' },
                                                {field: 'status', displayName: 'Status' },
                                                {field: 'current_user_id', displayName: 'Current_user' },
                                                    {cellTemplate:'<button id="editBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="linking()" >Edit</button> '}]};

              }
            ]);
```

And my index.html.erb

```
    <div ng-controller='asset.linkCtrl'>
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
    </div>
```

And got my thing working :)